# How can I tell the text alignment on a UITextView when the default is set to UITextAlignmentNatural

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, right-to-left, nslayoutmanager

I have a `UITextView` that has the property `UITextAlignmentNatural` but I want to know if the text is aligned left-to-right or right-to-left. How can I tell if it's LTR or RTL

For more context, I'm trying to do this within my `NSLayoutManager` subclass because I'd like to highlight the left-to-right and right-to-left cases with special formatting / outline.

Comment: Check this topic -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352342/ios-determine-if-device-language-is-right-to-left-rtl

Comment: That method doesn't really work. For a UIView the `UISemanticContentAttribute` is generally `UISemanticContentAttributeUnspecified` which flips the view if it's RTL and leaves it as is for LTR. I'd like to know if I'm dealing with RTL or LTR which I can't possibly know from the attribute `UISemanticContentAttributeUnspecified`

Comment: I'm curious if there's some way to tell if the view is right to left or left to right when `UISemanticContentAttributeUnspecified` is specified.