# Support NSDirectionalEdgeInsets for UIButton's contentEdgeInsets?

Tags: ios, localization, uikit, uiedgeinsets, insets

I would like to use `NSDirectionalEdgeInsets` to `UIButton`'s [`contentEdgeInsets`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624036-contentedgeinsets) and `titleEdgeInsets`. Is that possible?

### Background

For localization purposes, an iOS application may be required to adapt to both Left-To-Right and Right-To-Left languages when setting up a component's insets.

Apple introduced [`NSDirectionalEdgeInsets`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsdirectionaledgeinsets) with iOS11, unfortunately this was applied to few properties only like [`directionalLayoutMargins`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/2865930-directionallayoutmargins), deprecating [`UIEdgeInsets`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiedgeinsets) which is used for [`layoutMargins`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622566-layoutmargins).

`NSDirectionalEdgeInsets` honors interface layout direction using **leading** and **trailing** modifiers instead of **left** and **right** which is used by its counterpart `UIEdgeInsets`.

### Current Improper Solution

Using the following code for every button/view with every modified `UIEdgeInsets` property is quite cumbersome and prone to errors when making changes:

```
let isRTL: UIUserInterfaceLayoutDirection = // logic to determine language direction 

if isRTL == .leftToRight {
    nextButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 0)
} else {
    nextButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 10)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solution

```
import UIKit

extension UIView {
    // Returns `UIEdgeInsets` set using `leading` and `trailing` modifiers adaptive to the language direction
    func getDirectionalUIEdgeInsets(top: CGFloat, leading: CGFloat, bottom: CGFloat, trailing: CGFloat) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        // NOTE: this wil be deprecated when Apple use `NSDirectioanlEdgeInsets` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsdirectionaledgeinsets) for your insets property instead of `UIEdgeInsets`

        if self.userInterfaceLayoutDirection == .leftToRight {
            return UIEdgeInsets(top: top, left: leading, bottom: bottom, right: trailing)
        } else {
            return UIEdgeInsets(top: top, left: trailing, bottom: bottom, right: leading)
        }
    }

    /// Returns text and UI direction based on current view settings
    var userInterfaceLayoutDirection: UIUserInterfaceLayoutDirection
    {
        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            return UIView.userInterfaceLayoutDirection(for: self.semanticContentAttribute)
        } else {
            return UIApplication.shared.userInterfaceLayoutDirection
        }
    }
}
```

### Usage

```
nextButton.contentEdgeInsets = nextButton.getDirectionalUIEdgeInsets(top: 0, leading: 10, bottom: 0, trailing: 0)
```

I looked for an answer on Stackoverflow and found nothing. Thus I am sharing my answer.

### Credits

Thanks to [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40846035/10830091) by *David Rysanek* for `userInterfaceLayoutDirection` extension.